# How can i pass this Javascript Dictionary Key and Value Into A Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

This Dictionary called dict has the Table Id Selectors as the Keys and "Hellos" as the Values.

How can I pass this Dictionary into this function called applyDictionary that takes in the tableId key and value "Hellos" from the dictionary??

This function doesn't take in the jQuery Selectors IDs as Parameters as in I cannot pass Dictionary Table Keys with the #.

For Example I cannot pass applyDictionary(#tbl, 'hello');

Only applyDictionary(tbl, 'hello');

```js
var dict = {
  '#tbl': 'hello',
  '#tbl1': 'hello1',
  '#tbl2': 'hello2',
  '#tbl3': 'hello3',
};
applyDictionary(table_ID, value);
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish; what's the desired output of `applyDictionary`?

Comment: You can try applyDictionary('#tbl', 'hello');

Answer (score 1):

Get the entries of the object first, and for each entry, apply the function with the id and the value, and then get rid of the first character of the id.

```
Object.entries(dict).map(([id, value]) => applyDictionary(id.slice(1), value))
```

Explained:

```
Object.entries(dict) // Get entries of the object as 2-items arrays with the key and the value
  .map(([id, value]) => // destructure every item
    applyDictionary(
      id.slice(1), // Get rid of the first character and pass it as first argument to applyDictonary
      value, // Pass the value as 2nd argument
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.entries()`

Example:

```
var tblnsnsearchresults_tooltips  = {
    '#tblnsnsearchresults_uoicd': 'hello',
    '#tblnsnsearchresults_nsnid': 'hello1',
    '#tblnsnsearchresults_fsccd': 'hello2',
    '#tblnsnsearchresults_nsndescription': 'hello3',
};

let applycolumnheadertooltips = entries =>
    entries.forEach(([gridId, tooltips])=>console.log(`${gridId} => ${tooltips}`));

    applycolumnheadertooltips(Object.entries(tblnsnsearchresults_tooltips ));
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/entries